# ImageView no Android é possivel dar zoom?

Tags: java, android, xml

Na `ImageView` tem como dar zoom na imagem  dentro campo da `ImageView` definida.

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o que pretende.

Comment: @ramaral é  assim tenho uma imagem no imageView, fazer movimento de abrir o polegar com indicador os seja movimento de de zoom na tela aumentar a imagem que esta na imageView, será que tem jeito.